# How to upload a file in Sharepoint 2010 using c# console

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, console-application

Is there a way to automatically upload a file in Sharepoint 2010 using c#? We have no administrative control on the Sharepoint server. We just need to write a program that will upload a local file to a designated sharepoint library. The program will run on our server which in no way affiliated with the sharepoint server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following options could be considered for uploading the file into SharePoint via CSOM.

Prerequisites: [SharePoint Foundation 2010 Client Object Model Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21786)

### Using `FileCollection.Add` method

[FileCollection.Add method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.filecollection.add(v=office.15).aspx) adds a file to the collection based on provided file creation information

```
public static void UploadFile(ClientContext context, string uploadFolderUrl, string uploadFilePath)
{
    var fileCreationInfo = new FileCreationInformation
    {
        Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(uploadFilePath),
        Overwrite = true,
        Url = Path.GetFileName(uploadFilePath)
    };
    var targetFolder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(uploadFolderUrl);
    var uploadFile = targetFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInfo);
    context.Load(uploadFile);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Usage

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
     ctx.Credentials = credentials;
     UploadFile(ctx,"Documents/Orders",@"c:\upload\user guide.docx");
}
```

where  `Orders` is a folder in `Documents` library

According to [Uploading files using Client Object Model in SharePoint 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2010/03/12/uploading-files-using-client-object-model-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx):

> The above code might fail throwing a (400) Bad Request error depending
>   on the file size.

### Using `File.SaveBinaryDirect` method

[File.SaveBinaryDirect method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.savebinarydirect(v=office.15).aspx) - uploads the specified file to a SharePoint site without requiring an ExecuteQuery() method call.

```
public static void UploadFile(ClientContext context, string folderUrl, string uploadFilePath)
{
    using (var fs = new FileStream(uploadFilePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadFilePath);
        var fileUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}", folderUrl, fileName);
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(context, fileUrl, fs, true);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
     ctx.Credentials = credentials;
     UploadFile(ctx,"/News/Documents/Orders",@"c:\upload\user guide.docx");
}
```

where  `Orders` is a folder in `Documents` library located on web site `News`.

`FolderUrl` format: `/<web url>/<list url>/<folder url>`